# Java spring security - intercept subdomain url for different login?

Tags: java, spring, security, subdomain

I have an application with spring security installed and working well -- it is currently running out of `www.exampledomain.com`.

I now want to expand the application running out of a subdomain. For example `newapp.exampledomain.com`.

The only problem is that for this new app a user needs to log in. In spring it is very easy to intercept urls via `<intercept-url pattern="/Admin/*" access="ROLE_GENERAL"/>`

but what do you do when you want to intercept a subdomain for login? For example the following doesnt work for me:

```
<intercept-url pattern="http://newapp.exampledomain.com/*" access="ROLE_GENERAL"/>
```

Any thoughts on how to get around this?

Comment: You're using the same webapp in the subdomain, not a different webapp?

Comment: You may overwrite `FilterSecurityInterceptor` to add subdomain checks, but it smells like a hack, not a real solution. Upvote your question for out-of-the-box solution. Also, could you be some more specific about web-app/web-container subdomains configuration.

Comment: Yeh using the same app for different sub domains, the different sub domains represent different functionality to the user but the same server handles it (for cost effectiveness reasons). As for web app container subdomains config, a filter is in place to find the subdomain called and then the request is forwarded onto the relevant action for that domain funtionality. Imagine free.domain.com which all can access and the pro.domain.com which is a much better look and feel with added functionality.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to write your own AccessDecisionVoter which extends [RoleVoter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.html) and adds an additional check based on the hostname. Something like this:

```
public class MyVoter extends RoleVoter {
  public int vote(Authentication authentication,
                java.lang.Object object,
                java.util.Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
    FilterInvocation filterInvocation = (FilterInvocation) object;
    HttpRequest request = filterInvocation.getHttpRequest();
    // get subdomain from request
    String subdomain = getSubdomain(request);
    if ("free".equals(subdomain)) {
      return ACCESS_GRANTED;
    }
    else {
      super.vote(authentication, object, attributes);
    }
  }
}
```

Then wire up your voter:

```
<security:http auto-config="true" 
               use-expressions="true" 
               access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager">
...
</security:http>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager"
      class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.acme.MyVoter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

If you wanted to take it a step further you could also write your own [configuration attributes](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/ConfigAttribute.html) which would allow you remove the hardcoded hostname checks in the voter and do something like:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/Admin/*" access="ROLE_GENERAL" domain="free.acme.com" />
```

Comment: intercept-url tag never gets an attribute called "domain", in any of spring-security version. Using voter might be true, but this solution would never work.

Answer (score 1):

In your session cookie, domain should be explicitly set to exampledomain.com.

Application server is responsible for session cookie creation (JSESSIONID) but not Spring Security.

All you have to do is to inform your app server that you want to always have the same domain in cookie.

Add to your web.xml:

```
   <session-config>
        <cookie-config>
            <domain>exampledomain.com</domain>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```