# Adding sub domains to spring security authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, subdomain

I am trying to build a cloud solution which will behave as a complete different application on a sub domain. The problem which I face now is handling this sub domains during sign up and login. We are using spring form login for login. Every user who signs up should be treated as a user for only that specific sub domain and he should not be allowed to login from another sub domain. All the sub domains are dynamically created sub domains.

For example, a user with name "shrek" who has an account in "ogre.mydomain.com" should not be allowed to login from "human.mydomain.com" until and unless signs up from "human.mydomain.com" with same name or a different name.

**What I have tried**

I tried associating sub domain to a user and verified the user by appending the sub domain to the user name during login.

The problem with this approach is every time I ask for the principal in my controller I am getting the domain as a part of the user name.

I was just wondering if there is a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is instead of using the subdomain in username what you should do is have a role for each subdomain.

When a user is registered in `ogre.mydomain.com` named `shrek` then that user will automatically get a role named `ROLE_OGRE_USER` and with the following spring security restriction.

```
public class MyVoter extends RoleVoter {
  public int vote(Authentication authentication,
                java.lang.Object object,
                java.util.Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes) {
    FilterInvocation filterInvocation = (FilterInvocation) object;
    HttpRequest request = filterInvocation.getHttpRequest();
    // get subdomain from request
    String subdomain = getSubdomain(request);
    if ("ogre".equals(subdomain)) {
      if(authentication.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_OGRE_USER"))) {
         return ACCESS_GRANTED;
      } else {
         return ACCESS_DENIED;
      }
    }
    else {
      return super.vote(authentication, object, attributes);
    }
  }
}

<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" 
           access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"

</security:http>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager"
  class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
<property name="decisionVoters">
    <list>
        <bean class="MyVoter" />
    </list>
</property>
```

Read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9910331/java-spring-security-intercept-subdomain-url-for-different-login)